# How to generate a template JSON based on json-schema

Tags: json, documentation, jsonschema

I'm working on a project where I need to add JSON files to a repository to generate some test data. I need to document the file's format so every new developer can rely on that documentation to generate new files.

I'm considering using [json-schema](http://json-schema.org/) to document and I found a really useful online tool called [jsonschema](https://jsonschema.net/) (surely most of you know it already). What I need to know is if there is some tool to do the inverse task, which is: based on a schema, generate a template JSON based on the schema. For instance, having the schema

```
{
  "definitions": {}, 
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#", 
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json", 
  "type": "object", 
  "title": "The Root Schema", 
  "required": [
    "checked", 
    "dimensions", 
    "id", 
    "name", 
    "price", 
    "tags"
  ], 
  "properties": {
    "checked": {
      "$id": "#/properties/checked", 
      "type": "boolean", 
      "title": "The Checked Schema", 
      "default": false, 
      "examples": [
        false
      ]
    }, 
    "dimensions": {
      "$id": "#/properties/dimensions", 
      "type": "object", 
      "title": "The Dimensions Schema", 
      "required": [
        "width", 
        "height"
      ], 
      "properties": {
        "width": {
          "$id": "#/properties/dimensions/properties/width", 
          "type": "integer", 
          "title": "The Width Schema", 
          "default": 0, 
          "examples": [
            5
          ]
        }, 
        "height": {
          "$id": "#/properties/dimensions/properties/height", 
          "type": "integer", 
          "title": "The Height Schema", 
          "default": 0, 
          "examples": [
            10
          ]
        }
      }
    }, 
    "id": {
      "$id": "#/properties/id", 
      "type": "integer", 
      "title": "The Id Schema", 
      "default": 0, 
      "examples": [
        1
      ]
    }, 
    "name": {
      "$id": "#/properties/name", 
      "type": "string", 
      "title": "The Name Schema", 
      "default": "", 
      "examples": [
        "A green door"
      ], 
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    }, 
    "price": {
      "$id": "#/properties/price", 
      "type": "number", 
      "title": "The Price Schema", 
      "default": 0.0, 
      "examples": [
        12.5
      ]
    }, 
    "tags": {
      "$id": "#/properties/tags", 
      "type": "array", 
      "title": "The Tags Schema", 
      "items": {
        "$id": "#/properties/tags/items", 
        "type": "string", 
        "title": "The Items Schema", 
        "default": "", 
        "examples": [
          "home", 
          "green"
        ], 
        "pattern": "^(.*)$"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

running the tool I should obtain something like

```
{
  "checked": false,
  "dimensions": {
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0
  },
  "id": 0,
  "name": "",
  "price": 0.0,
  "tags": [
    ""
  ]
}
```

which is, a template with the default values. Online tools are preferred, but if you can provide me some Node/Ruby utility, it's also welcomed.

Thanks in advance for your answers/comments. Best regards

Answer (score 2):

With some research I found [json-schema-faker.js](https://json-schema-faker.js.org/) which accomplish the requirement checking the `useDefaultValue` option